# Real Snow Addon not working well

Tags: add-on

I have a problem with the built in addon "Real Snow", I have a really bad result when I'm using it.
I've tried on many kind of mesh, and I've enabled or disabled experimental cycle renders.

I'm using Blender 3.0.

Thank you a lot for help !
[image]

Comment: could you please share your .blend file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Edit > Preferences > Viewport* and deselect the *GPU* box under *Selection and Subdivision*.

Comment: Hey, sorry didn't see your answer 2 years ago..
Of course project finished long time now, but still want to thank you for answering. :)